# How can I setSelected for a ButtonGroup where all its JRadioButtons were created in a loop?

Tags: java, swing, enums, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I've got the following `for` loop creating `JRadioButton`s for the `ButtonGroup` `btgrpDiff` for each of the values in my `Difficulty` `enum`:

```
private enum Difficulty {
    EASY("Easy"),
    MEDIUM("Medium"),
    HARD("Hard"),
    EXTRA_HARD("Extra Hard");

    public final String name;

    private Difficulty(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

for (Difficulty diff : Difficulty.values()) {
    JRadioButton radDiff = new JRadioButton(diff.name);
    radDiff.setActionCommand(diff.name);
    btgrpDiff.add(radDiff);
    panDiff.add(radDiff, "align 50%, shrink 2, wrap");
}
```

How can I `setSelected` for the `ButtonGroup` `btgrpDiff` outside of the `for` loop? I'd like to either set it straight after they're all selected or have a boolean parameter for each difficulty level in my enum to determine whether or not they get set as selected in the `for` loop, but I'm not sure which would be best, or how exactly to get the `ButtonModel` for the `JRadioButton`s.

Comment: on creation throw them in a list, then you can iterate through the list running the method on all buttons you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon creation put your buttons in an ArrayList.

as class variable you should have

```
ArrayList<JRadioButton> mylist = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>()
```

So inside the loop do:

```
mylist.add(new JRadioButton(diff.name));
```

then you can access them anytime you want using `mylist.get(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Or put them in a Map, then you can get them directly:

```
Map<Difficulty,JRadioButton> rButtons = new HashMap<Difficulty,JRadioButton>();

for (Difficulty diff : Difficulty.values()) {
  JRadioButton radDiff = new JRadioButton(diff.name);
  rButtons.put(diff,radDiff);
  btgrpDiff.add(radDiff);
...
}
```